# Simple Update & Upgrade Script Not Working as Intended?

Tags: scripts, kubuntu, 17.04

I made a simple script just consisting of `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`. When I execute it (After making it executable) via Konsole, it just does the `update` part and truncates the `upgrade` part. Any way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change it to:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y
```

- `-y`: answer yes to confirmation.

---

After running `sudo apt upgrade` it will ask you to confirm whatever you want to upgrade the system or not, using `-y` you are saying yes to this kind of questions by default.

Comment: I use an **alias** of `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` and it works without need for `-y` and I have the option to continue or not at the `Y/n` prompt. But this is on Kubuntu 16.04's konsole.

Comment: @DKBose Don't know what can be the cause of problem. maybe the output of `sudo apt update &> /dev/null && echo $?` from OP's konsole be helpful to diagnose the problem, or running the command like : `update; upgrade` instead of using `&&` just to testing it out.

Comment: Could it be that OP's using a script rather than an alias?

Comment: @DKBose No, the script would output the question to the stdout just like an alias.

Comment: @Ravexina the output of your commands was nothing in Konsole.

Comment: @SarahSzabo what about:  `sudo apt update &> /dev/null; echo $?`

Comment: It outputs `100`.